# How to mock Android classes with PowerMock?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, powermock

Can I use [*PowerMock*](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) to mock Android classes called from with the class under test?

Example:

```
private static void appendProduct(StringBuilder builder, Product product) {
    Time time = product.getTime();
    // Product#getTime() calls Time#setNow() internally
    String formattedTime = DateUtils.getFormattedDateTime(time);
    builder.append(product.getTitle());
    builder.append(formattedTime);
}
```

Normally, this cannot be tested because an Android class is invoked. The following error is shown when I try nonetheless:

> RuntimeException: Method `setToNow` in `android.text.format.Time` not mocked.

In my test I do not care what `getTime()` returns. It would be great if I can mock the return value.

Comment: I dont get your exact problem. You are mocking "product"; but you are unable to have getTime() return something that doesn't break the test/production code?

Comment: To put it simple: I want to write a unit test for `appendProduct()`. I am not trying to mock `product`.

Comment: And how do you envision to test appendProduct(), that is using product ... without being able to control product then?